# Angular Material email validation is not working on Template driven form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

Can you tell me why this is not working? `<mat-error *ngIf="email.errors.email">`. But this is working fine. `<mat-error *ngIf="email.errors.required">   Email is required.`

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && submit()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="model.email"
                 #email="ngModel" email="true" required>
                <mat-error *ngIf="email.errors.email">
                    Email is invalid.
                </mat-error>
                <mat-error *ngIf="email.errors.required">
                    Email is required.
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. It should be like so.

Note: `?` is the important part.

```
<mat-error *ngIf="email.errors?.email && !email.errors?.required">
                Email is invalid.
</mat-error>
```

Comment: The question mark is known as a "safe navigation operator": https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths